# Filter out integers from the list of tuples

Tags: python

How can I filter out of the following list with tuples inside only the numbers to another list with the integers?

This is my List:  `[(10, '♦️'), (10, '♠️'), (8, '♠️'), (6, '♣️'), (9, '♦️')]`

And I want to get another list with the integers:  `[10, 10, 8, 6, 9]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the cards, unpack each of them into a rank and a suit, and only keep the rank:

```
ranks = [rank for (rank, suit) in cards]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [x[0] for x in old_list]
```

see [the tutorial on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *nested list comprehension* with `isinstance(n,` **`int`**`)` to check whether the element is integer:

```
>>> my_list = [(10, '♦️'), (10, '♠️'), (8, '♠️'), (6, '♣️'), (9, '♦️')]

>>> [n for t in my_list for n in t if isinstance(n, int)]
[10, 10, 8, 6, 9]
```

Refer ["isinstance" document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) for more details.

---

If all your numbers are going to be at 0th index of each tuple, then you can use `zip`:

```
>>> list(zip(*my_list))[0]
(10, 10, 8, 6, 9)
```